# "AccessDenied" When Call CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I got "AccessDenied" error when I follow the [Microsoft's article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt203787.aspx) to use AudioDeviceInputNode class. Here is my code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
  private AudioGraph graph = null;
  private AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInputNode = null;

  public MainPage() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }

  private async Task CreateAudioGraph() {

    // Create an AudioGraph with default settings
    AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);

    CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

    if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success) {
      // Cannot create graph
      await new ContentDialog() {
        Title = "Error",
        Content = String.Format("AudioGraph Creation Error because {0}", result.Status.ToString())
      }.ShowAsync();
      return;
    }

    graph = result.Graph;

    // Create a device input node
    CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult inputDeviceNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCategory.Other);

    if (inputDeviceNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success) {
      // Cannot create device input node
      await new ContentDialog() {
        Title = "Error",
        Content = String.Format("DeviceInputNode Creation Error because {0}", inputDeviceNodeResult.Status.ToString()),
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
        IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = false
      }.ShowAsync();
      return;
    }
    deviceInputNode = inputDeviceNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;
  }

  private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await CreateAudioGraph();
  }
}
```

But I am able to run the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation). Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. When you want to use AudioDeviceInputNode, you need to open Package.appxmanifest in your project and check the "Microphone" in Capabilities tab.